# Breaking down vectors with multiple variables

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a vector $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb R^3$, is it valid to say;

$(a,b,c) = a\cdot(1,0,0) + b\cdot(0,1,0) + c\cdot(0,0,1)$

Comment: Absolutely fine. I would like to ask why you thought there was anything wrong in that statement.

Comment: A little bit new to mathematical rigour and I'm using this idea in a assignment that posses risk to incorrect use of it.

If you would like to know; I'm finding a basis for a subspace depicted in the form of a cartesian equation. Worth little points relatively.

Comment: Oh, I appreciate your thought of verifying even something relatively trivial here on this website (+1 for the question). Do continue to ask on this website, you are welcome here. Besides, no questions are trivial at the beginner level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly IF the basis for  (a,b,c) is the standard basis for R3....bit if the basis was v1 = ( -2 , 0 , 0 ) , v2 = ( - 1  , 2 , 0 ) and v3 = ( 1 , - 3 , 5 ) then ( a ,  b , c ) means " a v1 + b v2 + c v3 "...so you can see the BASIS of the vector space is all important when you write the vector